# VSTO C# Excel modify and save xltx file

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am building a VSTO add-on to replace the string "Engineer" to "Designer" in every worksheet of all the excel files in the directory. So far, my code is working except for xltx files.

```
FileInfo[] listOfFiles = d.GetFiles("*.xltx*").ToArray();

foreach (FileInfo file in listOfFiles)
            {

                var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName);

                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                xlWorkSheet.Range["A1"].Value = "Hello World";

                xlWorkBook.Save();
                xlWorkBook.Close();
            }

            xlApp.Quit();
        }
```

This code works only for all files except for `.xltx`. I think I cannot save `.xltx` files the same way by doing `.Save()`. How should I modify `.xltx` file and save it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059056/opening-an-excel-template-xltx-as-an-excel-template-not-a-workbook) should help.

Answer (score -1):

For template excel files such as xltx, xltm, use xlWorkBook.SaveAs() function instead of .Save()